# Is it possible to prove Mordell's conjecture geometrically?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X/k$ be a smooth curve of genus $g>1$ over a number field $k$.
By the Faltings theorem (nee Mordell's conjecture), the set of $k$ - rational points 
$X(k)$ is finite. Due to the Mordell-Weil theorem, Faltings's theorem is a consequence 
of the following statement:
If $X$ is a *complex* smooth curve of genus $g>1$, and $\Gamma\subset J$ 
is a finitely generated subgroup of the Jacobian $J=Jac(X)$, then $X\cap \Gamma$ is finite.

The latter statement is purely geometrical (and known to be true). So it is natural 
to try to prove it using geometric methods, but as far as I know, nobody did this. 
Are there any promising approaches towards geometric proof of the 
Faltings theorem? (I have heard of Chabauty's method, but probably it doesn't work 
for $\mathbb{C}$.)

Comment: This is a good question. It has always struck me that the only known proofs of the Mordell conjecture over number fields, as well as of the Manin-Mumford conjecture require arithmetic models. The only thing I know in the "purely complex" (or "geometrical") direction is Zannier-Pila's approach to Manin-Mumford (but not Mordell...), which still requires arithmetics, but less so than Raynaud's (or Ullmo-Szpiro-Zhang, or Pink-R.'s).

Comment: In light of the recent breakthrough by Lawrence and Venkatesh (recent as in July 2018), perhaps it is worthwhile to look at this question again.